# How to use Map as query paramter with pagination in jpa springboot

Tags: jpa, query-string

How to use HashMap<String, List< String >> as query paramter in jpa springboot with pagination

Comment: I don't think you can use HashMap<String, List< String >> directly as query paramter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can use Spring Expression Language in the query.

Example:

```
@Query("select e from Employee e where e.name = :#{#map.get('name')}")
List<Employee> findEmployees(Map<String, String> map);
```

or even shorter

```
@Query("select e from Employee e where e.name = :#{#map['name']}")
List<Employee> findEmployees(Map<String, String> map);
```

Works also with IN

```
@Query("select e from Employee e where e.name in :#{#map['name']}")
List<Employee> findEmployees(Map<String, List<String>> map);
```

Comment: As per my understanding you are equating value of key "name" while what i want to do is ...

Map<String, List<String> > map

e.name in map.keySet() and e.department in map.value("matchedKeyForName")

Comment: This works as well. I just added an example. You should try it out in some unittests

Comment: okay, i tried and getting the below mentioned error